# Need Simplify vlookup command for textbox value in vba

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I want to create 700 texboks whose value is taken from the vlookup vb function. But after reaching 300, I can warn of excess procedure.

```
Private Sub Extra_Change()  
Dim ycNo As Integer
If Me.NumberLook.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "bla..bla..bla!!!", vbExclamation, "some text"
Exit Sub
End If
ycNo = NumberLook.Value
Me.TextBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 3, 0)
Me.TextBox2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 4, 0)
Me.TextBox3.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 5, 0)
Me.TextBox4.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 6, 0)
Me.TextBox5.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 7, 0)
Me.TextBox6.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 8, 0)
Me.TextBox7.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 9, 0)
Me.TextBox8.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 10, 0)
Me.TextBox9.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 11, 0)
Me.TextBox10.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 12, 0)
Me.TextBox11.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 13, 0)
Me.TextBox12.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 14, 0)
Me.TextBox13.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 15, 0)
Me.TextBox14.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 16, 0)
Me.TextBox15.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 17, 0)
Me.TextBox16.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 18, 0)
Me.TextBox17.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 19, 0)
Me.TextBox18.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 20, 0)
Me.TextBox19.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), 21, 0)
...
...
...
to 700
```

Maybe someone can solve this problem ..

Comment: Too much, and I think it could be a little shorten it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Since all items you are fetching belong to the same row, fetch it once, dont call VLookup 700 times!

2- fetch that row values in an array

3- loop on the controls and assign them from the array

```
Private Sub cmbNourut_Change()
  ...
  ycNo = NumberLook.value

  ' 1- Find the row by matching in column A
  Dim r: r = Application.Match(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:A55"), 0)
  If IsError(r) Then MsgBox ("not found blablah"): Exit Sub

  ' 2- Get the array of values from the found row starting at column C
  Dim ar: ar = Worksheets("mapel1").Cells(r, 3).Resize(, 700).Value2

  '3- Loop and assign text-boxes from the array
  Dim i as Long
  For i = 1 To 700
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).value = ar(i)
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your solution is helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Just implement a loop:

```
Private Sub cmbNourut_Change()
Dim ycNo    As Integer
Dim i       As Long

If Me.cmbNourut.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "bla..bla.bla!!!", vbExclamation, "...."
    Exit Sub
End If
ycNo = cmbNourut.Value
For i = 1 To 700
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ycNo, Worksheets("mapel1").Range("A1:AAX55"), i + 2, 0)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you .. the problem is over. To stop from the loop function?

Comment: @YanLimaBenua - What do you mean? How do you stop the loop? You can add `Exit For` to get out of the loop.  Is that what you mean? So, say you want to stop the loop after a condition is me. In the `For i = 1...` loop, you could add say `If i = 500 Then Exit For`.

Comment: Yes, true. I have tested the formula above and all went well. Thank you bro

Comment: @YanLimaBenua I'd either my, or ASH's answer, worked for you, do you mind flagging one as the answer (click the check left of the post). (Ash's solution is clever as it should be quicker than mine since it doesn't do a hundred+ lookups).

Comment: I wonder why there isn't anyautomatic reminder for it. It's almost becoming ridiculous. **I** will accept you answer ;)